# Why are so many JavaScript libraries talking about command line installation?

Tags: javascript, theory

I have apparently missed a shift in JavaScript culture; now I see JavaScript libraries (such as [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed), or a million others) that talk about installing them via command lines via *npm*. This is of course very different from the simple notion of `<script src ='...'></script>`.

My question is *not* 'what is npm', but what is going on in the culture of JavaScript development - the paradigm shift itself.

And if all this is about node.js, then why don't these libraries very clearly state on the tops of their download pages (or where ever) that their library is a node.js library?

> command line? what are you talking about!? ... it's JavaScript!

Comment: Doesn't the documentation for modernizer make that clear? The npm install is for a tool that lets you make a custom build of modernizr with only the features you want to include in it.

Comment: To put a fine point on it, "what is going on in the culture of js development" is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Quentin, he doesn;t know what a "npm install" is, node js itself is relatively new and unknown to most people.

Comment: @seahorsepip — From the question: "My question is not 'what is npm', but what is going on in the culture of js development"

Comment: When I think of 'custom build', I think of IDE development with Eclipse ... and if I want to customize some library I download, I just open the .js file and change it ... the very notion of 'custom build' in the javascript culture seems misplaced ... hence my question

Comment: @apsillers ... I didn't say anything like that at all ... if you have an explanation that will explain why this new approach is better, I would like to know ... because currently I do not know ... hence my question

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question I also ask a team worker about it (He said that's it helps when updating a lot of servers- don't understand why & how). Anyway, your question is good, don't know why people downvotes

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I misread your comment to mean that custom-built libraries make sense, but not in a JavaScript context. I see now that you mean they don't *ever* make sense to you. That is an easy question to answer (i.e., for a modular library like Modernizr, you only need a few functions from it, rather than the many it offers, so you can save download time for your users by trimming out unnecessary parts), but the question about "what is happening in JavaScript culture" is to nebulous to answer clearly. Perhaps you want to ask, "What the technical advantages to a custom build in JavaScript?"

Comment: actually you saying "technical advantages to a custom build in JavaScript" implies something that is going on in the culture today ... that's actually a part of the answer ... although I am not 100% sure of what it means ... I have only used a few libraries in my code over the years: jquery, raphaeljs, jquery mobile ... ... and neither of them dealt with any issues along the lines of "custom building" ... so in and of itself that leaves me (and thousands of other js people) confused ... but you did give me a piece of the puzzle, so I appreciate it ...

Answer (score 3):

What's going on with JavaScript is the exact same thing that's already happened for Java with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html), and for Python with [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) (to name just two). Complex software has dependencies, and satisfying those dependencies can be resolved in one of three ways:

1. include all the dependencies together with the software package
2. make the developer hunt down, download, and bring together all the dependencies
3. describe the dependencies in a standardized way and use software to automatically install the dependencies

The first option has problems of code size and complexities of updating dependencies and sub-dependencies to newer versions (e.g., if I want to update package A, and it depends on B and C, which don't need updates, do I then need to re-download the bundled B and C anyway?). The second option was the state of the art in client-side JavaScript, and it is a tremendous pain if you have a nontrivial number of dependencies. The third option is a package manager, like NPM, or Maven, or pip, or the like the software manager for a GNU/Linux distribution.

As for concerns like, "Command line?? Don't my client-side scripts run in the browser?" -- yes, you *run* the code in the browser, but you *get* your dependencies using a package manager tool that runs on the command line. The command lines tools are solving the problem of *downloading many software libraries*, which is a task totally separate from the context in which the code actually runs.

Comment: so npm is a work station issue ... something I do during development on my work machine?